# scope is undefined Karma-jasmine-angular unit testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to setup a basic test with jasmine in my angulajrs app.Am currenly trying to test a controller function.

This is my controller function :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.name = 'Kool G Rap';
}])
```

My test spec :

```
describe('MainCtrl', function () {

    var mainCtrl, scope;

    beforeEach(module('nikko'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        mainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });

    }));

    it('should assign the correct rapper to scope', function () {
        expect(scope.name).toEqual('Kool G Rap');
    });

});
```

When I run the test I get the error **Cannot read property 'var' of undefined**.

Does somebody know why the scoped variable is still undefined? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works just fine over here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/1eYtUfLZ2kn7sb0ED6Mb?p=preview (even with `var`)

Comment: @Phil .I didnt add "var app = angular.module('nikko', []);" in the controller file.Is it necessary to add "var app = angular.module('nikko', []);" to my every controller file ?

Comment: No but you do have to define your `nikko` app *somewhere* and have that script loaded by karma

Comment: Thanx a lot :) @Phil